# Newbie here, need some help for slidable horizontal button collection

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

I'm an utter and complete beginner to Xcode. I've joined this app developer internship, but they are implementing a self directed learning approach for our assignments and I am completely swamped. I have never done any kind of coding before, so I was hoping to get some answers here.

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var didTap:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing:320){
                Button(action: {
                    didTap = !didTap
                    
                }
                ){
                    VStack {
                        Text("12").font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(didTap ? Color.white : Color.black)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text("Monday").font(.system(size: 11))
                            .foregroundColor(didTap ? Color.white : Color.black)
                    }.frame(width: 70, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                        .background(didTap ? Color.gray: Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 6)
                        
                    }
                
                
                Text("")
                    
            }.background(.red)
            
            Button  {
                self.didTap = true
                } label: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("12").font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text("Monday").font(.system(size: 11))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }.frame(width: 70, height: 85, alignment: .center)
                        .background(.white)
                        .background(didTap ? Color.blue : Color.yellow)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 6)
                }
            ColorPicker(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Title"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, selection: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.constant(.red)/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .padding(.trailing,180)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This is my app's home page design
[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbwDP.png)

And this is what I've got so far
[After hours of trying and reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYcVw.png)

My app is a simple reminder app. There are a lot to work on but I'm trying to make a collection view comprised of buttons that show the dates in a user's current week. If you click the buttons, the date along with the reminders will change to reflect the selected date. You are also supposed to be able to swipe left or right to change into the previous / next weeks.

Appreciate any kind of feedback since I am such a moron when it comes to these kinds of tech-y stuff.

Comment: Welcome! Please share some code with us so that we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello, how do I post long lines of code? EDIT: nevermind, I've edited the original to include my codes

Comment: This is a moderately complicated thing you are trying to do. The issue really isn't the view code so much as you don't have a data model. The view flows from the data model, and until you organize that, you can't really write the view well. Please study [Apple’s SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford’s CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/). You need more background before you attempt something like this.